# Problem with UITableView clear color

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a tableview in grouped style. When I set the tableview background color to clear color then I see dark black corners around the tableview. Is there a way to solve this problem and remove those dark corners?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Along with using `clearColor`, use the following:

```
[tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[tableView setOpaque:NO];
```

Comment: On the iPad in particular, when your table is inside a UISplitViewController's popover, you must set the backgroundView to nil in order to achieve a transparent background. That isn't necessary on the iPhone. Your comment helped me figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set a UIView and set clear color to it. This works for me.

```
UIView *backView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = backView;
```

Comment: this makes my cell to go transparent and I dont want that. I want my cell be of white color and I just want to remove those black corners.